# Access denied to domain but not domain controllers

Tags: active-directory

An AD DS domain `internal.example.co.uk` is made up of DC servers `EX-SRV-WIN-01` and `EX-SRV-WIN-02`.

Browsing to `\\EX-SRV-WIN-01`, `\\EX-SRV-WIN-01.internal.example.co.uk`, `\\EX-SRV-WIN-02`, and `\\EX-SRV-WIN-02.internal.example.co.uk` succeeds.

[image]

Browsing to `\\internal.example.co.uk` fails with error `Access is denied` - this prompt rejects all given credentials including domain administrator.

[image]

Pinging `internal.example.co.uk` correctly resolves to the IP address of one of the domain controllers so DNS is working correctly.

Forcing a Group Policy update completes successfully.

[image]

So, this issue seems to be limited to SMB but affects all PCs (Windows 7 and Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a certification, Group Policy had been configured with hardened UNC paths which included, among others, the following entry:

```
Value name                  Value
\\internal.example.co.uk    RequireMutualAuthentication=1, RequireIntegrity=1
```

Correcting the value to `\\internal.example.co.uk.` resolved the issue.